# How to append to form "Thanks for the email!" after submit button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm building a contact form for my website and I would like users to enter their information, click submit, have the information process with php and to just have a message display on the bottom of the form. Originally, I was redirecting to another page and the form was working properly, but now I just want to append a small message and can't get it to work.

This is what I have currently in my contactengine.php file for it to process all the variables and send the email.

```
if ($success){

THIS IS WHAT I DID BEFORE THAT WORKED BUT HAS TO REDIRECT
// print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index_thanks.html\">"; // 

//BELOW IS WHAT I WANT TO OCCUR
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#contact-area").append("Thanks for your message!")
</script>

}
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between client-side and server-side and the HTTP lifecycle.

Comment: Ok. But what specifically am I doing wrong here? PHP is a server side language and JS is client side, correct? So I can't mix the two I'm assuming?

Comment: Tip: `echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";` etc.

Comment: Ah, are you using an AJAX op? I've answered on how to handle form submission using a traditional server round-trip. If you are, please retag your question with `ajax`, since it is relevant.

Comment: ^ How are you getting on with this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript for this. JavaScript is great, but it should only be used where necessary, since it can add some brittleness to the user experience.

Here's a possible design approach:

- Set up a POST form
- Process the form, set a session variable to thank the user, and redirect to the form again. This switches the browser from POST to GET mode<sup>†</sup>, and is usually as simple as this:

  ```
  header('Location: http://yourdomain.com/form.php');
  exit();
  ```
- Render the form as usual. If a session variable is set to thank the user, render the thank you message, and unset the session variable<sup>‡</sup>

I wouldn't use a `<meta />` refresh here - it needs to load more data to work, and is more fiddly to implement.

---

<sup>†</sup> The POST-redirect approach is a common design pattern in web development. There are plenty of resources about this on the web, if you are unfamiliar with it. It fixes problems associated with rendering web content inside a POST method, particularly in relation to page refreshing and using the back/forward buttons.

<sup>‡</sup> These temporary session variables are sometimes known as *flash variables*. They exist from one HTTP operation to the next, and are erased at the end of the second operation.

Comment: I need a little more detail on how I can do this but I like your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put JavaScript inside of your PHP code. However, I will give you an explanation of what you need to do.

On the **client side**, bind an event for the click, then

```
$('form button').click(function() {
    $.post('file.php', {'object': 'property'}, function(success) {
         if(success) {
             $("#contact-area").append("Thanks for your message!")
         }
    });
});
```

On the **server side**, you will process this:

```
//file.php

$sentByAJAX = $_POST['object'];
return true;
```

Comment: Where would I put the server side code? in the same php file I was working with? contactengine.php? just copy and paste what you wrote?

Comment: pretty much! you could go /server/file.php to keep it away from your front-end code :)

Comment: is object and property just standard syntax like success? or do I need to fill that in?